# Does $E[1/f]\overset{d}\to 1/E[f]$ for $\operatorname{Tr}H=1,\operatorname{Tr}H^2=0.5$?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Suppose $x$ is a Gaussian random variable in $d$ dimensions with $H=E[xx^T],\ \operatorname{Tr}(H)=1,\operatorname{Tr}(H^2)=0.5$. Take $m$ I.I.D. samples of $x$ and stack them as rows of $X$.

Is it possible to show that the following holds as $d\to \infty$?

$$E\left[\frac{1}{\operatorname{Tr}X^T X X^T X}\right] \to \frac{1}{E\operatorname{Tr}(X^T X X^T X]}$$

If we assume that spectrum of $H$ obeys power law decay, we can take $\lambda_i = c_1 i^{c_2}$, and solve for $c1,c2$ to satisfy the constraints. Taking $d$ to infinity, the gap in approximation shrinks.

- Does the gap shrink to zero?
- Is this behavior specific to power law decay?

[image]

If this holds for slightly more general $\operatorname{Tr}X^T X A X^T X$, we can choose $A=I$ to prove [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/587824/does-e-frac1-x-4-rightarrow-frac1e-x-4-in-high-dimensions) and $A=\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T$ to prove [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430892/how-fast-does-this-gaussian-random-walk-move-away-from-the-origin)

Comment: Do you assume that $x$ is centered?

Comment: Anyways, this looks like a concentration property: if a sequence of positive random variables $(Z_n)$ satisfies $Z_n/a_n \to 1$ in probabiliity for some sequence $(a_n)$ of positive numbers, if furthermore the sequences $(Z_n/a_n)$ and $(a_n/Z_n)$ are uniformly integrable, then $E[Z_n]/a_n \to 1$ and $a_nE[1/Z_n] \to 1$, so $E[Z_n]E[1/Z_n] \to 1$.

Comment: In simulations I'm seeing property hold for both centered and uncentered Gaussians

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}\newcommand{\de}{\delta} $

Let us show that the desired convergence will never take place.

First here, note that
\begin{equation*}
U_d:=\tr(X^TXX^TX)=\sum_{a,b=1}^d\sum_{j,k=1}^m x_{ja}^2x_{kb}^2,  \tag{1}\label{1} 
\end{equation*}
where $x_{ja}$ is the $a$th coordinate of the random vector $x_j$, given the iid copies $x_1,\dots,x_m$ of the random vector $x$, with $Exx^T=H$, $\tr H=1$, and $\tr(H^2)=1/2$. Since no conditions on $Ex$ are specified, assume for simplicity that $Ex=0$. Then the conditions $Exx^T=H$, $\tr H=1$, and $\tr(H^2)=1/2$ imply
\begin{equation*}
    EU_d=m(m+1). \tag{1.5}\label{1.5}
\end{equation*}

So, the desired convergence is
\begin{equation*}
    E\frac1{U_d}\to\frac1{EU_d}=\frac1{m(m+1)} \tag{2}\label{2} 
\end{equation*}
as $d\to\infty$.

This would imply that
\begin{equation*}
    V_d:=\dfrac{U_d}{EU_d}\to1 \tag{2.5}\label{2.5}
\end{equation*}
(in probability, as $d\to\infty$), because for each $\de\in(0,1)$
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{\de^2}{1+\de}\,E1(|V_d-1|\ge\de)\le E\frac{(V_d-1)^2}{V_d}=EV_d+E\frac1{V_d}-2\to0. 
\end{equation*}

Let us diagonalize the matrix $H=Exx^T$ by writing $H=QDQ^T$ for a diagonal matrix $D$ and an orthogonal matrix $Q$. Letting then $y:=Q^T x$ and $y_j:=Q^T x_j$, we have $X^T X=Q_m Y^T Y Q_m^T$, where $Q_m$ is the block-diagonal matrix with $m$ diagonal blocks each equal $Q$ and $Y:=[y_1,\dots,y_m]^T$. So, $U_d=\tr(X^TXX^TX)=\tr(Y^TYY^TY)$. Thus, wlog we have \eqref{1} with all the random variables (r.v.'s) $x_{ja}$ with $(j,a)\in[m]\times[d]$ independent (and centered Gaussian); as usual, $[m]:=\{1,\dots,m\}$. Also, the distribution of $x_{ja}$ does not depend on $j$.

Now straightforward (but long) calculations show that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    EU_d^2&=m (m+2) (m+4) (m+6) t_8 \\ 
    &+4 m^2 (m+2) (m+4)(t_6 t_2-t_8) \\ 
    &+3 m^2 (m+2)^2(t_4^2-t_8) \\ 
    &+6 m^3 (m+2)(t_4 t_2^2-2 t_6 t_2+2t_8-t_4^2) \\ 
    &+\frac{24}{4} m^4\Big(\frac{t_2^4}{6}-t_2^2 t_4+\frac{4t_2t_6}{3}+\frac{t_4^2}{2}-t_8\Big), 
\end{aligned}
\tag{3}\label{3}    
\end{equation*}
where $t_{2p}:=\tr(D^p)=\tr(H^p)$, so that $t_2=1$ and $t_4=1/2$, and hence
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    EU_d^2&=m (m^3 +6 m^2 +  m (3 + 32 t_6) + 48 t_8).  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
The minimum of the latter expression given the logconvexity conditions $t_6\ge t_4^2/t_2=1/4$ and $t_8\ge t_6^2/t_4=2t_6^2$ is $m^4+6 m^3+11 m^2+6 m=(m(m+1))^2+2 m (m+1) (2 m+3)$ and hence, in view of \eqref{1.5},
\begin{equation*}
    Var\,V_d=\frac{EU_d^2}{(EU_d)^2}-1\ge\frac{2 (2 m+3)}{m (m+1)}. \tag{4}\label{4}    
\end{equation*}

It is similar to but much easier than \eqref{3} to show that $EU_d^4=O(1)$ and hence $EV_d^4=O(1)$, in view of \eqref{1.5} (where the constants in $O(\cdot)$ can depend only on $m$). So, $(V_d-EV_d)^2=(V_d-1)^2$ is uniformly integrable in $d$. So, in view of \eqref{2.5}, $Var\,V_d=E(V_d-1)^2\to0$ as $d\to\infty$, which contradicts \eqref{4}. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Right...modified the question to restrict to the case which has been experimentally observed

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov : I suggest that your ask only one question in this one post, about only one particular covariance structure (rather than two structures, as you have it now), especially given that your original question has been answered.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, rolled back the edits and forked changes into separate question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431228/when-does-e1-f-oversetd-to-1-ef

Comment: Thanks for the updated analysis....does this imply that the observed behavior (two quantities seemingly converging to each other) does not hold in the limit? Or merely that concentration is the wrong tool to show this?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov : This analysis shows that the convergence never takes place -- because the convergence would imply the concentration (2.5), which never takes place.